# UIActivityViewController share image only for FB, Twitter and Mail, but not messages

Tags: swift, facebook, uiactivityviewcontroller

So I am using the following code to get the text for all the UIActivityTypes.

```
        @objc func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> AnyObject {
        return ""
    }

    @objc func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: String) -> AnyObject? {
        if activityType == UIActivityTypeMessage {
            return "String for message"
        } else if activityType == UIActivityTypeMail {
            return "String for mail"
        } else if activityType == UIActivityTypePostToTwitter {
            return "String for twitter"
        } else if activityType == UIActivityTypePostToFacebook {
            return "String for facebook"
        }
        return nil
    }

    func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, subjectForActivityType activityType: String?) -> String {
        if activityType == UIActivityTypeMessage {
            return "Subject for message"
        } else if activityType == UIActivityTypeMail {
            return "Subject for mail"
        } else if activityType == UIActivityTypePostToTwitter {
            return "Subject for twitter"
        } else if activityType == UIActivityTypePostToFacebook {
            return "Subject for facebook"
        }
        return ""
    }   
}
```

And this is where the interesting part happens. I add an image from an URL to the objectsToShare array. This would work fine if I wanted the image to be shown for all, but my issue is that I don't want to show the image for the `UIActivityTypeMessage`. That one should just contain the text, and no image. How can I do this?

```
    // Load image to share
let articleURL = URLBuilder.sharedInstance.addOnlyHttps((promo?.imageUrl)!)
KingfisherManager.sharedManager.cache.retrieveImageForKey(articleURL, options: nil) { (image, _) -> () in
    if image != nil {
        objectsToShare.append(image!)
        self.openShareViewController(objectsToShare, sender: sender )
    } else {
        KingfisherManager.sharedManager.downloader.downloadImageWithURL(NSURL(string: articleURL)!, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: { (image, error, imageURL, originalData) in
            if image != nil {
                KingfisherManager.sharedManager.cache.storeImage(image!, forKey: articleURL)
                objectsToShare.append(image!)
                self.openShareViewController(objectsToShare, sender: sender)
            }
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: I need some clarification,you have to share image and text through UIActivityViewcontroller. **Exception** UIActivityTypeMessage should only have text not image.right?

Comment: @Gokulvivid spot on good sir :D that's indeed what I need

Comment: check my answer it may full-fill your need.

Comment: @Gokulvivid your answer was just what I needed, thanks! works like a charm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To set different Content for different ActivityItem's the best was is to use **UIActivityItemSource**.For more info on ActivityItemSource check this [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityItemSource_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIActivityItemSource).
2. You are already following the same way,so it is easy to get solution for your problem.
3. Create two UIActivityItemSource class as below

   **SourceOne:**

   ```
   class MyStringItemSourceOne: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
   @objc func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> AnyObject {
      return ""
   }

   @objc func activityViewController(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: String) -> AnyObject? {

      if activityType == UIActivityTypeMessage {
        return "String for message"
      } else if activityType == UIActivityTypeMail {
       return "String for mail"
      } else if activityType == UIActivityTypePostToTwitter {
       return "String for twitter"
      } else if activityType == UIActivityTypePostToFacebook {
       return "String for facebook"
      }
      return nil
      }
   }
   ```
4. By adding above code,we set **String Content** that to be shared.Note depending upon activity activityType we set different string values.
5. Our requirement is to set image for all activityType expect **UIActivityTypeMessage**,So that we are going to create another **UIActivityItemSource**

   **SourceTwo**

   ```
    class MyStringItemSourceTwo: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
    @objc func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> AnyObject {
       return ""
     } 

    @objc func activityViewController(activityViewController:  UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: String) -> AnyObject? {

       let Image: UIImage = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03589/Wellcome_Image_Awa_3589699k.jpg")!)!)!
       if activityType == UIActivityTypeMessage {
          return nil
       } else if activityType == UIActivityTypeMail {
       //return "String for mail"
          return Image
       } else if activityType == UIActivityTypePostToTwitter {
          return Image
       } else if activityType == UIActivityTypePostToFacebook {
          return Image
       }
       return nil
      }

   }
   ```
6. Next add the above two source's to UIActivityViewController as **activityitems** as follows

   ```
   @IBAction func Test(sender: AnyObject) {

      let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [MyStringItemSourceOne(),MyStringItemSourceTwo()] as [AnyObject], applicationActivities: nil)
      //NOTE: Instead of using rootviewcontroller go with your own way.
      if let window = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)?.window
      {
         window.rootViewController?.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
      }
   }
   ```
7. Now everything will work fine as per your requirement.